# Compiler error when running Simulink models from Visual Studio

Tags: c++, header, compilation, simulink

I have compiled all subsystems of a big, complex, Simulink model into a series of dlls. All of them are working in Visual Studio except one. The one that is not working is the only one that requires the simstruc.h header file, and I get about 120 error messages when I try to compile them. Most of them are in simstruc.h, but also in subsequent includes, like sfcn_bridge.h for example. All of them look the same way:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*' c:\matlabr2011b_x86\rtw\c\src\sfcn_bridge.h (37) 
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int c:\matlabr2011b_x86\rtw\c\src\sfcn_bridge.h (37)

.

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*' c:\matlabr2011b_x86\simulink\include\simstruc.h (2135) 
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int c:\matlabr2011b_x86\simulink\include\simstruc.h (2135)
```

The code in the line in above example looks like this:

sfcn_bridge.h (37):

```
SS_SimMode *simModePtr;
```

simstruc.h (2135):

```
SparseHeader* slvrJacobianMatrix;
```

I have been able to compile programs that include simstruc.h before, but suddenly it's not working. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is the header file simstruc_types.h present in the include files folder?

Comment: Yes, simstruc_types.h and simstruc.h are in the same Matlab folder and that folder is listed in C/C++>General>Additional Include Directories. That's the correct way of doing it, right?

Answer (score 0):

Check if any of your class declaration missing ";" at the end.

```
class AAA
{
}; <--- this one
```

**Edit:**

Try these tips as well.

- Rebuild the project
- Right Click on each cpp file and click "Compile" to identify infected files.
- Check include paths. specially sub folders in simulink include directory.
- Go to the declaration of SparseHeader struct and check if it get skipped by any #ifdefs or any preprocessor definitions.
- If your code base is small, comment out half of it until you get a compilable code. This is not easy however.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I could unfortunately not find any missing semi-colons.

Comment: @FabianJonsson Were you able to resolve this? I am facing the same issue.